# For some reason my Vagrantfile creates errors

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Error messages

```
PS D:\Users\user\Desktop\nxbt> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'generic/ubuntu2010' version '4.2.16' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9000 (guest) => 9000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
A customization command failed:

["usbfilter", "add", "0", "--target", :id, "--name", "TP-Link UB5A Adapter ()", "--product", "TP-Link UB5A Adapter", "--manufacturer", "", "--productid", "0604", "--vendorid", "2357"]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["usbfilter", "add", "0", "--target", "2b551c47-0ff9-4833-833b-841207314af9", "--name", "TP-Link UB5A Adapter ()", "--product", "TP-Link UB5A Adapter", "--manufacturer", "", "--productid", "0604", "--vendorid", "2357"]

Stderr: Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 7.0.10
Copyright (C) 2005-2023 Oracle and/or its affiliates

VBoxManage.exe: error: Unknown option '0604'

Usage:

  VBoxManage usbfilter add <index,0-N> <--target= <uuid | vmname | global> >
      <--name=string> <--action=ignore | hold> [--active=yes | no]
      [--vendorid=XXXX] [--productid=XXXX] [--revision=IIFF]
      [--manufacturer=string] [--product=string] [--port=hex]
      [--remote=yes | no] [--serialnumber=string] [--maskedinterfaces=XXXXXXXX]
>

Please fix this customization and try again.
```

I have used a custom Vagrantfile here:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2010"

  # Publically forwarded ports.
  # The below ports are accessible to all machines on the same network.
  # To limit access to the local network, add "host_ip".
  # Eg: config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000 # Web App
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000 # Remote server

  # Explicitly create a shared folder of the Vagrantfile directory at /vagrant in the VM
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

  # Install NXBT
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y python3-pip bluez bluetooth pkg-config build-essential libdbus-glib-1-dev libgirepository1.0-dev
    cd /vagrant
    pip3 install -e .
  SHELL

  # Enable USB Controller on VirtualBox
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "2048"
    vb.cpus = 2
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "on"]
    vb.customize ["usbfilter", "add", "0",
        "--target", :id,
        "--name", "TP-Link UB5A Adapter ()",
        "--product", "TP-Link UB5A Adapter",
        "--manufacturer", "",
        "--productid", "0604",
        "--vendorid", "2357",]
  end
end
```

I am on Windows 11 and i have python3, vagrant and VirtualBox all installed with no issues. I am quite new to this and just want NXBT to work. I have all of the things needed but still get that error. Any detailed help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to replace the productid option to 0x0604 but then I got these errors Line 35: There is an unexpected string literal, "TP-Link UB5A Adapter ()", after the :id option in the usbfilter command. Line 35: There is an unexpected comma, ,, after the "TP-Link UB5A Adapter ()" string literal in the usbfilter command. Line 35: There is an unexpected comma, ,, after the "manufacturer" option in the usbfilter command. Line 35: The usbfilter command is missing an end parenthesis, ) I was expecting it to continue with vagrant up as normal so that I could vagrant ssh into it.